# How to simplify this Cauchy Riemann integral?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose we want to calculate the integral $\int_C \frac{1}{1+z^6} dz$, where C is, for exxmple, the semicircle of radius 2 where the imaginary is positive.

This integral has, theorically, nothing difficult apart from its laborious hand writting.

What i mean is, first we need to find six roots, which is easy: $z_i = e^{i(\pi / 6 + \pi n / 3 )}, 0 <= n <= 5$.

The problem, comes now, to find the residues. I think you can see what i mean: We would need to put ${1+z^6}$ as the product of six $z-x$ factors, where x are the roots. After this, we would need to substitute z as one root, excluding of course the factor that contain the root itself (becoming now a fraction of five factors). We would need to do that more two times because of the other two roots that the semicircle includes. And at the end sum everything and multiply by $2 \pi i$

This is gonna be a huge account, huge time lost and possibly increasing the chance of error.

Is there a smarter way to solve it? A more simply way?

Comment: The semicircle of specifically radius 1 is a problem, since there are poles on this circle -- I think radius 2 will give the desired integral.

Comment: @AlexNolte Ops, yes, suppose radius two so

Comment: Are the residues of any use for computing an integral along a semicircle?